How can I position a fixed dialog element horizontally using the right property?
I know that I can position HTML-elements with position: fixed; horizontally using the right CSS property as stated in mdn web docs However, this does not seem to work as I expected with the dialog-element. Altough I found a workaround for my use case with margin-left: auto I'm still wondering: Why does the dialog element not stick to the right side just like a div? Positioning it to the top, bottom or left seems to work fine. I'm working with Chromium.


dialog,
div {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

dialog {
  /*margin-left: auto;*/
}
<dialog open>dialog</dialog>
<div>div</div>




The dialog element has inset-inline-start: 0px; inset-inline-end: 0px; set via the browser stylesheet, and those appear to influence the behavior.

@CBroe Ah I see, makes sense. If you want to write that up as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

The dialog element has inset-inline-start: 0px; inset-inline-end: 0px; set via the browser stylesheet, and those appear to influence the behavior.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset-inline-start:

The inset-inline-start CSS property defines the logical inline start inset of an element, which maps to a physical offset depending on the element's writing mode, directionality, and text orientation. It corresponds to the top, right, bottom, or left property depending on the values defined for writing-mode, direction, and text-orientation.

So in normal writing mode and direction, the effect of these should be the same, as if left and right were set to 0.
So in your above example, in addition to right: 0;, you would have to set left: auto, to "override" this.

the explanation is here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width .. If the values are over-constrained, ignore the value for 'left' (in case the 'direction' property of the containing block is 'rtl') or 'right' (in case 'direction' is 'ltr') and solve for that value
